# Web Application: RAP tool kit

Tags: html-editor

I want to develop a web application in java. I am using eclipse juno release 2. I need a toolkit like the one in visual studio, where we drag & drop the controls for developing user interface. I found RAP plugin for the same. Can anybody tell me whether it will serve the purpose?Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAP provides a widget toolkit with [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) API, hence you can use the SWT Designer, which is part of the Eclipse [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) project.

[This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWindowBuilder/article.html) will help you get started with the SWT Designer. The UIs created with this tool can also be used with RAP, as long as you avoid controls that are not supported by RAP (such as StyledText).